# IE 9 won't display the links or rollovers on my site, but previous version of IE will

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I don't know what it is, but IE just isn't showing any part of the navigation of a slider I'm building. I have not even gotten to the point of adding JavaScript. Its just a simple side-tab menu with a rollover. The only thing peculiar about it is that I'm using `display:table` and table-cell in order to center a group of links vertically in the middle of each tab. Oh and I'm using `@font-face` for the fonts.

[highschooltalentbattles.com/homepage](http://highschooltalentbattles.com/homepage)

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I guess I didn't realize that IE9 was more strict in some regards than previous versions. Just needed to add a width to the enclosing divs.